# Divergence theorem on a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $T\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the interior of a triangle, let $u \in H^1(T)$, let $v \in C^\infty(\overline{T})$.

Then, called $n$ the outer normal of $T$: $$ \int_T v\partial_i u \, dx = \int_{\partial T} v \operatorname{trace}(u) n_i \, d\sigma-\int_T u \cdot \partial_i v \, dx$$

Can anyone please provide me a reference where this version of divergence theorem is stated and proved? I would like a precise statement, but not overly complicated or overly general, a version of divergence theorem that can "barely" handle this type of situations.